# Retrieving files with read attribute and classifying them

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have gotten this code from somewhere else with a little editing which allows to go through all the directories with the starting path specified using `enumeratorAtPath`. With this code i am able to retrieve files with a certain extension which has read attribute using `isReadableFileAtPath`. What i would like is to retrieve all files with any extension which has read attribute and classify them into different categories based on their last folder name.
Example if i have a path /a/b/c/example.plist, /a/b/c/example.plist would be classified under c.

```
- (NSString *) retrievePaths
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSMutableString *filePaths = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:@"/"];
    NSString *nextItem = [NSString string];
    int i = 0;
    while( (nextItem = [dirnum nextObject]))
          {
              if([[nextItem pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"db"] || [[nextItem pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"sqlitedb"] || [[nextItem pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"sqlite"]) {
                  if([fileManager isReadableFileAtPath:nextItem])
                  {
                      i++;
                      [filePaths appendFormat:@"%d)",i];
                      [filePaths appendString:nextItem];
                      [filePaths appendString:@"\n"];
                  }
              }
          }
    NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Paths : %@", filePaths];
    return format;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove below if condition from your code and you will be able to get all files with readable access permission

```
if([[nextItem pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"db"] || [[nextItem pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"sqlitedb"] || [[nextItem pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"sqlite"])
```

**EDIT**

*Updated function try this, will work for you..*

```
- (NSString *) retrievePaths
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSMutableString *filePaths = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSString *path = @"/Assign/your/path/"; // assign your path 
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:path];
NSString *nextItem = [NSString string];
int i = 0;
while( (nextItem = [dirnum nextObject]))
{
    NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:nextItem];
    BOOL isDir = NO;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:&isDir];
    if(NO == isDir) {
        if([fileManager isReadableFileAtPath:filePath])
        {
            i++;
            [filePaths appendFormat:@"%d)",i];
            [filePaths appendString:nextItem];
            [filePaths appendString:@"\n"];
        }
    }
}
NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Paths : %@", filePaths];
return format;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing it before, but doing it will also print out paths which I do not want to.

Comment: which path you don't want, please be specific.

Comment: for e.g. deleting the line which u provided will also print out paths which does not contain any file
It will print out /a/b/c which does not contain any file.
I would like to only print out paths which has files in it such as
a/b/c/test.txt

Comment: To be clearer, if I delete that specific code, it will print out any path, with or without files in it

Comment: sorry but can you please check again this answer(I did some more editing) ? this code is working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! it works perfectly now. Just have to change the enumerator path since i would like to start reading from "/". Is it possible if u can edit the code to suit my 2nd requirement which is to categorise them into last folder name since right now it will print everything in order

Comment: Hey I edited my answer, now it will give only name of those files which has read permission.

Comment: Is it worked for you? if it is than please upvote & accept it

Comment: yup it works, but that just half of my question that you answered. Anw I have upvoted it alrdy. 1 more question. Even if i tried to read from the main directory which is "/", I am not able to read the files in some folders such as /Applications, /var or /etc. Is there a reason to it? Is it because they are soft links?

Comment: First of all man, this is not good Idea to read "/" dir from iOS because every application in iOS is sandboxed and can only use specific directories i.e. sandbox directory. I think your are running this app in simulator that's why it is getting files of "/" but I'm not sure it will work on iPhone/iPad same way or not.

Comment: I am running it on a jailbroken phone and my app is stored in /Applications

Comment: ok I haven't worked on jailbroken device yet. Now which part of your question is unanswered, tell me I'll try to answer it.

Comment: Really thankful for your patience. The part right that is left is to categorize all these output paths into different categories.(Right now what I thought of is to categorize them based on the last folder name). U might have a better suggestion on how to categorize them

Comment: before I'll give any suggestion to you, first I need to know, how you are going to use that sorted/categorized data. As far as categorization based on name concern we already achieve it. if it works for you nothing like it.

Comment: I was thinking on the same idea too that since this function already sort of read the paths in an orderly manner. I was wondering if a clearer distinction can be made. I am just using this categorization as a reference

Comment: I checked this function in my iPhone, this function perfectly reading all file inside /Application,/var,/etc but not from /.Trash, may be trash doesn't contain anything.