# How does the iPhone sandbox block accessibility of files in other sandboxed app?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sandbox

I have created an jailbroken application in objective c which enumerates the entire iPhone system starting with "/" path and outputs file paths which are readable using `isReadableFileAtPath` which can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537088/retrieving-files-with-read-attribute-and-classifying-them). However after running the applications which has the same code in 2 different environments `/Applications` and `/var/mobile/Applications`, I realise that the file paths retrieved in my output are the same. My application in `/Applications` would be able to retrieve any file path since it is not in the sandboxed folder. However the same application in `/var/mobile/Applications` is able to read the files in another Application which was installed from the Appstore(Which I thought the sandbox would prevent it).

So my question is in what way does the sandbox prevent accessibility of files since using `isReadableFileAtPath` does not work at all.
 Do I have to code something that is able to check whether the file is accessible by opening the file like this code, where if the content is NULL if its not accessible? I really hope that someone would clear my misconception as I am new in IOS

```
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox doesn't prevent apps from opening certain types of files. It only allows apps to read and write files from a limited number of directories (the app's "sandbox" directories). The file system does not give apps full access to the entire "disk". Jailbreaking a phone breaks this restriction.

Comment: Meaning to say that for e.g if I have installed App A and App B in /var/mobile/Applications which is the sandbox directory, App A will only be able to read and write files in its own sandbox folder will not be able to access App B files? If you say that the sandbox only allow apps to read/write in the sandbox directories,if App A uses isReadableFileAtPath method to try to read App B sandbox files, it will always return false for any path that is not in its own sandbox? Am i right to say that?

Comment: I kind of understand that you are trying to say in layman terms if both App A and App B are installed in the sandbox directory which is /var/mobile/Applications, App A will not be able to read/write App B files since each App is in its own sandbox. However if App A has a code which uses isReadableFileAtPath, it will return true for any path enumerated, including paths in App B which should not be the case